# clarity between q.uniqueResult() and q.list() in queries

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Consider the following query statement

```
Query q = getSession().createSQLQuery("select ...");
q.uniqueResult();
```

My question is do we have to use

a) `q.uniqueResult()` when the query returns only a single row

b) `q.list()` when the query returns multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Let me make it clear.

When you know, You will receive only one value (not one row) - Go for `uniqueResult()`.
General used on SQL Functions like- max ,count functions

For List- the method name itself says it is a `List of Items`.

EDIT:

If you except a single row.

```
List<YourBean> list = new ArrayList<YourBean>();
//HQL stuff using .list()

    if (list.size() > 0) {
                yourBeanRef= list.get(0);
    }
```

Comment: If the query returns only one row then which method do we have to use. will it be same                                                    
 q.uniqueResult. I am a bit confused.

Comment: changed the answer, on your request for single row.